# Set URL as per the term plan

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using Wordpress site where I have monthly, yearly and Biannually plans. At this moment I can set only one link for order now button.

What I want is , I want to set set specific URL as per the term plan. For example

```
For monthly : a=add&pid=1
For anually : a=add&pid=2
for bianually : a=add&pid=3
```

Here is my code if you want

```
<div class="price white-text regular-font"><span>
class="price_val">$4.95</span> /mo</div>
<select class="plans-select">
<option value="$4.95">Triennially</option>
<option value="$5.95">Biannually</option>
<option value="$6.95">Aannually</option>
<option value="$7.95">Monthly</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="transparent-btn btn1"><a class="lightgrey-bg black-text
regular-font" href="#">Order Now</a></div>
```

At this moment there is a drop down menu to select term.  Now sure how to change link for Order now as per the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use four buttons with different `href` URLs instead of the select and option elements.

Or you use a real HTML `<form>` with `type="get"` and your target URL as `action` attribute, which will attach those `pid` values to the URL if you add `name="pid"` as an attribute to the `select` tag.

Answer (score 0):

1 Change

```
<option value="$6.95">Aannually</option>
```

to

```
<option value="3">Aannually $6.95</option>
```

similar modification for others

2 add this script

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('.plans-select').on('change', function () {
          var plan_id = $(this).val(); 
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = 'a=add&pid=' + plan_id; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

You can also have a price / plan object if you have to have the price in option value

```
prices = {'$6.95':3, .......}
```

And use it to get the `plan_id` by the selected `value` such as `$6.95`

Don't forget loading jQuery before the script section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: something like: `var price = $(this).val();` `var plan_id = prices[price];`

Comment: It depends on what you are going to do next.

Comment: Your code works perfectly, I am just stuck at one stage. How can I use a=add&pid=1 for order now tab ?